# Is there an easy way to filter stderr in a gradle Exec task?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have an Exec task that runs a command (Inkscape, in "no-gui" mode). This command is incredibly noisy, and tends to spew out a lot of unimportant warnings to stderr. Some of the things it sends to stderr are useful, however, so I don't want to completely suppress its stderr.

Currently I have a wrapper shell script that uses `grep -v` to filter out messages from stderr that I know are pointless. I then have my Exec task invoke this script.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this more self-contained, though, so that I don't need to rely on an external shell script.

---

My gradle task looks something like this:

```groovy
task createIcon(type:Exec) {
    def outdir = new File(fromSvgDir, "drawable-ldpi/")
    outputs.dir(outdir)
    doFirst {
        outdir.mkdirs()
    }
    def svg = 'src/images/ic_launcher.svg'
    inputs.source(new File(svg))
    def png = new File(outdir, "ic_launcher.png")
    outputs.file(png)
    commandLine "$workingDir/svgToPng.sh", svg, png
}
```

and `svgToPng.sh` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
svg="$1"
png="$2"

exec inkscape -z -D -w 48 -e "$png" "$svg" 2> >(
    grep -v '^\*\* (inkscape:[0-9]*): CRITICAL \*\*: dbus_g_' |
    grep -v '^$' |
    grep -v '^Failed to get connection$' >&2
)
```

(Yes, believe it or not, those "CRITICAL" errors are inconsequential, and Inkscape actually succeeds in doing what it's supposed to do despite them.)

Comment: What do you have at the moment?

Comment: @tim_yates See the update to the question.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if you can filter process outstream on the fly, but you can certainly store output into your own stream and do any kind of processing/filtering/printing you want *after* the process exits.

Comment: @RaGe I think I'd be fine with it being post-processing rather than concurrent. How would I do this, though? How do I capture stderr from the command, and how do I emit to wherever stderr normally goes once the command has completed?

Comment: You'll have to set `errorOutput` and/or `standardOutput`, posting an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but some variation of this would likely work:

```
task createIcon << {
    def os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    def result = exec {
        def outdir = new File(fromSvgDir, "drawable-ldpi/")
        outputs.dir(outdir)
        doFirst {
            outdir.mkdirs()
        }
        def svg = 'src/images/ic_launcher.svg'
        inputs.source(new File(svg))
        def png = new File(outdir, "ic_launcher.png")
        outputs.file(png)
        commandLine "$workingDir/svgToPng.sh", svg, png
        standardOutput = os
    }

    def outputAsString = os.toString()
    def match = outputAsString =~ /somepattern/
    println match
}
```

You could also, depending on certain matches, stop the build by throwing an exception

```
throw new GradleException('error occurred')
```

Comment: Yes, using `errorOutput` should do what I want. Now I just need some sort of `GrepFilterOutputStream`.